# How to filter out data in a PHP array based on date and id?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of users here, the array has more than 2 users and each user array has a registration_date, licence_expiry_date, gender, email, age, and name.

The array looks like this.

```
$Users = Array(
                    (0) => Array
                        (
                            (id) => '100',
                            (name) => 'Name & Surname',
                            (email) => 'email@email.com',
                            (age) => '25',
                            (gender) => 'male',
                            (registration_date) => '2019-01-03',
                            (licence_expiry_date) => '2019-09-03',
                        ),

                    (1) => Array
                        (
                            (id) => '101',
                            (name) => 'Name & Surname 1',
                            (email) => 'email1@email.com',
                            (age) => '22',
                            (gender) => 'male',
                            (registration_date) => '2019-03-03',
                            (licence_expiry_date) => '2019-02-03',
                        ),

                    (2) => Array
                        (
                            (id) => '102',
                            (name) => 'Name & Surname 1',
                            (email) => 'email1@email.com',
                            (age) => '25',
                            (gender) => 'male',
                            (registration_date) => '2019-01-03',
                            (licence_expiry_date) => '2019-09-03',
                        ),

                    (3) => Array
                        (
                            (id) => '103',
                            (name) => 'Name & Surname 3',
                            (email) => 'email3@email.com',
                            (age) => '25',
                            (gender) => 'male',
                            (registration_date) => '2019-08-03',
                            (licence_expiry_date) => '2019-10-03',
                        ),

                    (4) => Array
                        (
                            (id) => '103',
                            (name) => 'Name & Surname 4',
                            (email) => 'email4@email.com',
                            (age) => '18',
                            (gender) => 'female',
                            (registration_date) => '2018-01-03',
                            (licence_expiry_date) => '2019-12-03',
                        ),
                );
```

What I want to achieve is to filter the data in this to another array but with some condition. For example, I want to filter this to only the users where the age is 25 and registration_date is after 2019-01-01 and licence_expiry_date before 2019-10-01.

The Expected results would look like this

```
$UsersFiltered = Array(
                    (0) => Array
                        (
                            (id) => '100',
                            (name) => 'Name & Surname',
                            (email) => 'email@email.com',
                            (age) => '25',
                            (gender) => 'male',
                            (registration_date) => '2019-01-03',
                            (licence_expiry_date) => '2019-09-03',
                        ),


                    (2) => Array
                        (
                            (id) => '102',
                            (name) => 'Name & Surname 1',
                            (email) => 'email1@email.com',
                            (age) => '25',
                            (gender) => 'male',
                            (registration_date) => '2019-01-03',
                            (licence_expiry_date) => '2019-09-03',
                        ),


                );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$UsersFiltered = array_filter($Users, function ($v) {
    return $v['age'] == 25 &&
           $v['registration_date'] > '2019-01-01' && 
           $v['licence_expiry_date'] < '2019-10-01';
});
```

Note that since your dates are in `YYYY-MM-DD` format they can be compared alphabetically without conversion to a `DateTime` object, timestamp or similar.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/sRb1t)

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_filter,

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($val){
    return ($val['age'] == 25 && strtotime($val['registration_date']) > strtotime('2019-01-01') && strtotime($val['licence_expiry_date']) < strtotime('2019-10-01'));
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/8nsnW).

I used > and < as a strict comparison as you didn't mention greater or lesser than equal to.

I use date comparison using strtotime.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) like this:

```
$licence_expiry_date = new DateTime('2019-10-01 00:00:00');
$registration_date   = new DateTime('2019-01-01 00:00:00');

$UsersFiltered = array_filter($Users, function($element) use ($licence_expiry_date, $registration_date) {
    return $element['age'] == 25
        && DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $element['registration_date']) > $registration_date
        && DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $element['licence_expiry_date']) < $licence_expiry_date;
});
```